# How to type hint specific constant string in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a getter function that retrieves stored values from an object. There is also a setter which sets a new value.

```
type IObjectType = {
    APP_ENV: string;
    APP_CONFIG: string;
    [key: string]: string;
};

const object: IObjectType = {
    APP_ENV: '10',
    APP_CONFIG: 'configString',
};

function get(key: string): any {
    return object[key];
}
```

I want Typescript to hint the constant keys of the object as shown below.

[image]

In the above image, I changed the type of `get` parameter, to get the hinting. What I want is the `get` function to accept any `string` as an argument and show hints if it is a mandatory key like `APP_ENV` or `APP_CONFIG`.

I tried the union operator

```
function get(key: "APP_ENV" | "APP_CONFIG" | string): any {
    return object[key];
}
```

The above does not work as TypeScript evaluates the signature to a string.

[image]

Is there any solution to this? Proper hinting can be really helpful when there are a large number of mandatory keys.

Comment: What IDE are you using? The auto completion is a feature of the IDE.

Comment: I am using VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on your IDE of course but using an overload might help:

```
function get (key: 'APP_ENV' | 'APP_CONFIG'): any
function get (key: string): any
function get (key: string): any {
  // code
}
```

Comment: To anyone reading this answer, the order of overload is really important. It has to come before the string parameter.